# Using the same machineKey across two web farms

Tags: iis, configuration, web-farm

We have two separate NLB web farms.

The first farm runs an app that delivers content to the customer facing application on the second NLB.

We've noticed a single Cryptographic error in our logs that occurs whenever a page loading content from the first farm is accessed.

Is there any reason to not give all of the servers in both farms the same machineKey settings?

Answer (score 1):

There is really no reason to not use the same machine key if your clusters are running the same code or sharing services. One thing that you should think about is that the machine key was really built for security reasons and you evaluate that before moving forward.

We have done this multiple times on different clusters and it works great.